# How to manage django'orm via aws redshift?

Tags: python, django, amazon-redshift

I'm a new developer for AWS redshift.

As far as, I knew AWS redshift is pretty similar to postgresql

Is there any library or module for manage(like auto-migration, auto migrate) between redshift and Django?

I did create a table and access data by using SQLAlchemy and redshift but I don't know how to do that thing in python Django.

any suggestion or idea is okay!!

I got this error with this command

```
python manage.py migrate


django.db.migrations.exceptions.MigrationSchemaMissing: Unable to create the django_migrations table (Column "django_migrations.id" has unsupported type "serial".
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could easily connect your RedShift services with your Django App.

Try to add the code below to your `settings.py` file

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': '[Your Cluster Name]',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'USER': '[Username ]',
        'PASSWORD': '[Password]',
        'HOST': '[Pathname]',
        'PORT': 5439,
    },
}
```

**But**, you need to know that Redshift doesn't enforce primary keys. In my opinion is not a great idea to use Redshift as your default DB in your Django Application as Redshift is a helpful DB for a data warehouse and not for an app.

To sump up, my suggestion is PostgreSQL.

Comment: what I wonder is, if connection like your suggestion, django'orm will support for fully feature like (python manage.py makemigrations...)...?

Comment: @user3773632, of course, you can. If you connect your DB like mentioned before you have access to all Django's ORM.